# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException - Call to undefined relationship [tasks] on model [App\Models\Status]

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-8

I am creating an app that shows the Tasks and the Status of the Task.

I am unable to create the relationship between the Status and Task or rather the Statuses of the Task.

This is the TaskController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = auth()->user()->statuses()->with('tasks')->get();
        return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:56',],
            'description' => ['required', 'string'],
            'status_id' => ['required', 'exists:statuses,id']
        ]);

        return $request->user()
        ->tasks()
        ->create($request->only('title', 'description', 'status_id'));
    }

    public function sync(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'columns' => ['required', 'array']
        ]);

        foreach ($request->columns as $status) {
            foreach ($status['tasks'] as $i => $task) {
                $order = $i + 1;
                if ($task['status_id'] !== $status['id'] || $task ['order'] !== $order) {
                    request()->user()->tasks()
                    ->find($task['id'])
                    ->update(['status_id' => $status['id'], 'order' => $order]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $request->user()->statuses()->with('tasks')->get();
    }
}
```

This is the Task Model

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Task extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'title', 'description', 'order', 'status_id'
        ];
    
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
    
        public function status()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Status::class);
        }
    
    }
```

This is the Status Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Status extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'slug', 'order'
    ];

    public $timestamp = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class)->orderBy('order');
    }
}
```

When I add the character `s` to the `public function task()` to show `public function tasks()` it resolves the error and shows the webpage.

However, this error still shows in VS Code.

```
Undefined method 'statuses'.
```

How do I resolve the error? Do I need to worry about the VS Code error or ignore it?

Edit: Here is the User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasTeams;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use HasTeams;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Status::class)->orderBy('order');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($user) {
            // Create Default Statuses
            $user->statuses()->createMany([
                [
                    'title' => 'Backlog',
                    'slug' => 'backlog',
                    'order' => 1
                ],

                [
                    'title' => 'Up Next',
                    'slug' => 'up-next',
                    'order' => 2
                ],

                [
                    'title' => 'In Progress',
                    'slug' => 'in-progress',
                    'order' => 3
                ],

                [
                    'title' => 'Done',
                    'slug' => 'done',
                    'order' => 4
                ]
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a relation named `statuses`? It's `status`

Comment: Do I need to create another relationship named statuses? as the task can have different statuses

Answer (score 0):

**WRONG ANSWER**

I think your problem lies in the User model, even though you didn't put it here. The relations you are calling, you are calling from

```
$request->user()->...
```

you probably haven't defined those relations.

Comment: The User model has the following

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Status::class)->orderBy('order');
    }

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I read your message in a wrong way. You have resolved the error. VS will continue to show that error (even though it is not), but if it works it should not be a problem. If it bothers you too much, I am sure there are some VS extensions that take care of that

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt.